# linux mdadm: recover overridden array

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid

I had 2 3TB disks in a RAID1 array as /dev/md2.

I tried to recover that array, by recreating it (which was probably stupid).
I issued

```
mdadm --create /dev/md2 --assume-clean --raid-devices=2 --level=1 /dev/md2 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1
```

I followed some guide on the net, but I think I screwed up, or the guide screwed up. Anyway, I have now a new array, with a new UUID, that does have neither a filesystem nor the data I had stored there.

Haven't touched it otherwise..

I saved the output of `mdadm --examine` of the old array to files. So I got the original metadata, and I have not touched or formatted the new array.

Can I, somehow, recover the old array?

Comment: See [this article](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_Recovery) which tells how to use the output of "mdadm --examine" to recreate. I hope that you haven't reformatted.

Comment: another advice, as you are using RAID1 try to recreate the array using only 1 disk. (declare the others as missing)

Comment: Can you post the output of the old --examine as well as running --examine again on the array? Depending on the metadata version, the metadata location might have changed, and that's why it looks empty now. If the metadata moved location or changed in size, you may have overwritten some part of the original data.

I think it will come down to comparing that metadata, and seeing where the data actually starts. At best, the real start of the filesystem might be further into the disk. At worst, you've overwritten the start or end of the filesystem with zeros (where metadata was).